# How can I rebrand Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04, files

How can I rebrand Kubuntu 22.04 LTS to make it so the about page in settings calls the operating system something other than Kubuntu?

I know there's a config file somewhere in regular Ubuntu but I wanted to know its location in Kubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found something I got from a forum in Discord called Cubic.
You can use it to edit the system's files before the installation. Here are the places to change: `/etc/lsb-release`, `/etc/issue`, `/etc/issue.net`, `/usr/share/backgrounds/` and `/usr/share/icons/`, especially `distributor-logo.svg`. Also change the Plymouth theme in
`/usr/share/ubiquity` and `/usr/share/ubiquity-slideshow`.

@Cubi I think the names come from `lsb_release`. So if you have changed that and do a `sudo grub-update` it should change. Or just change `GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR` in `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Best way to also make a spin off.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).